# How can I add a colour gradient or scale to vertices of an igraph?

Tags: r, igraph

This is a subset of my edge list.

```
  Source Target Freq
       1      2   18
       1      3   17
       1      4   32
       2      4   17
       3      4   37
       2      5   32
       1      6   24
       3      6   26
       4      6   33
       5      6   17
       2      7   12
       5      7   10
```

Here's a subset of my vertices dataset, g1.

```
Subject          c1         c2
1                18         0.052                                                                            
2                0          0.052
3                0          0.124
4                3          0.057
5                0          0.061
6                19         0.071
7                0          0.016
```

So I tried to add a colour gradient to my vertice using the scales package but it doesn't add any colour to my vertices.

```
library(igraph)
library(scales)
gradient <- cscale(V(g1)$c1, palette = seq_gradient_pal(low = "lightblue", high = "darkblue"))

layfr <- layout_with_fr(g1)     
plot.igraph(g1, layout=layfr,
            vertex.color = gradient,
            edge.width = 1)
```

I also tried adding a gradient using the ifelse function:

```
col1<-ifelse(V(g1)$c1 <=10, "lightblue", "darkblue")
```

Okay, interestingly, the gradient works with c2 but not with c1, where it leaves the vertices blank. Both their artibrutes are (v/n), I'm not sure if that helps.

Comment: I tried running the sample code you provided and it created a gradient for me https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSv35.png. Tested with `igraph_1.5.1`. I can't reproduce the issue with the information provided. What does `class(V(g1)$c1)` return for you?